# Limit superior of the number-of-divisors function $d(n)$

Tags: number-theory, limits, limsup-and-liminf, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(n):=\sum _{d|n} 1$ be the number-of-divisors function. Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate)) defines the limit superior of $d(n)$ by

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\overline{\text{lim}}}\frac{\log (d(n))}{\log (n)/\log (\log (n)) }=\log(2)$$

Rearranging terms gives

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\overline{\text{lim}}}\log (d(n))=\frac{\log (2) \log (n)}{\log (\log (n))}$$

$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\overline{\text{lim}}}d(n)=e^{\frac{\log (2) \log (n)}{\log (\log (n))}}$$

But plotting $d[(n)$ and $e^{\frac{\log (2) \log (n)}{\log (\log (n))}}$ out to $n=10,000,000$ shows little sign of the suprema converging on this limit superior - perhaps due to the small size of $n$?

Can someone confirm that the $\underset{n\to \infty }{\overline{\text{lim}}}d(n)$ given above is correct, and either show how it is derived or point me to a source?

Comment: No, they are nonsense.  LHS is $\infty$, RHS is a function of a free variable $n$.  You can't rearrange terms in this way.

Comment: The step $$\color{red}{\underset{n\to \infty }{\overline{\text{lim}}}\log (d(n))=\frac{\log (2) \log (n)}{\log (\log (n))}}$$ is mathematically absurd, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you both. Makes sense now! If you could post this as an answer, I'll tick it.

Comment: $\lim \sup \frac{\log (d(n))}{\log (n)/\log (\log (n)) }=\log(2)$ follows from the PNT, letting $n =\# k= \prod_{p\le k} p, \log \# k\sim k$.

Comment: @reuns, note 24 and 30 have the same number of factora

Comment: Hi @reuns. Can you point me to a full proof? I'm not experienced enough to figure it out for myself, as you can doubtless see from the OP!